# read and print a file line by line along with the line number and the total number of lines in each line in bash

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash that it reads a file line by line as a variable and in the output it prints the total number of lines, the number of each line, and the value of each line. for example:
file.txt :

```
123456
543215
655778
874595
865940
```

in output of bash I want:

```
0501 123456
0502 543215
0503 655778
0504 874595
0505 865940
```

for reading the file I found this:

```
filename="./file.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do 
    echo "$line"
done < $filename
```

and for calculate the number of lines I found this:

```
numberoflines=$(sed -n '$=' file.txt)   
for i in $(seq $numberoflines)
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not a terrible way to count the number of lines, but it's certainly less than ideal.  `wc -l < file.txt` is far more standard. (and about 10 to 20 times faster in a few non-rigourous tests)

Comment: But using the shell's builtin `read` to read the lines *is* a terrible thing to do.  I would expect that to be 100s if not 1000s of times slower than awk or sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
nl -w2 -ba -n rz filename | sed "s/^/$(wc -l < filename)/"
```

`nl` is a command line tool for numbering lines of file. That bunch of options is for making the output format look like the one you provide in the question. Check `nl --help` for more information.

`sed` command prepends total number of lines to output.